# List all files which are changed b/w two revision by a user

Tags: svn

```
svn diff -r16369:HEAD --summarize
```

Above command list all files which are changed b/w two revision.

But can i find all which which are changed above version r16369 by user 'sherkhan' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the search feature of log:

```
svn log -r16369:HEAD --search sherkhan -v
```

That might find revisions where sherkhan is mentioned in the log and isn't just the committer.

But you could write a script to filter those if you really wanted.  Or you could use `--xml` and write xslt.  Or you could use the bindings to write a program to do the searching.

I guess what you want to depends on how often you're going to use this and what your goals are.  But this should at least get you started.

**XSLT example**

For the hell of it I went ahead and produced an XSLT example

With the following in user-changed-paths.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="user"/>
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="log/logentry">
<xsl:if test="author=$user">
<xsl:for-each select="paths/path">
<xsl:value-of select="." /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then run the following command:

`svn log -r16369:HEAD --search sherkhan -v --xml | xsltproc --stringparam user sherkhan user-changed-paths.xslt - | sort -u`