# List of files changed since a certain date using SVN by specific user

Tags: svn

List of files changed since a certain date using SVN by specific user..

I have tried svn log | sed -n '/blankman/,/-----$/ p' but getting the error that 'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all files which are changed b/w two revision by a user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042774/list-all-files-which-are-changed-b-w-two-revision-by-a-user)  The only difference to this one is that you're asking for a date instead of a revision range.  Which only means changing the `-r` flag option to provide a date for the starting range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

> for i in `svn log -r{2012-11-01}:HEAD | awk '$3 == "user" {print $1}'`; do svn log -v -$i;done

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
svn log --search <username> -qv -r {2014-01-10}:HEAD
```

From `svn help log`:

> If the --search option is used, log messages are displayed only if the
>     provided search pattern matches any of the author, date, log message
>     text (unless --quiet is used), or, if the --verbose option is also
>     provided, a changed path.

So, the above command can also potentially return those commits where the date or the changed path contains the username. Hopefully, that would never be the case.